# Index array of every element in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

This might be a basic question.

To find out the maximum value and its index in array in MATLAB, I have used this code:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

[val, idx] = max(A, [], 2);
```

Now, how can I find the index array of all the element (not finding maximum)?

Comment: YOu create your list of indices and use setdiff to remove the maximum value index. Give an example to get apt help/ advice.

Comment: I think the max value index example above is causing confusion, I just want to get the index array of any 2D matrix.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

Comment: What is the expected result - the "index array" - for your example `A`?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate an array with an index to each element of `A`? That would simply be `1:numel(A)`. If you're asking for something different I suggest  you [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you want. Adding the expected result for your example case would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are talking bout subindices and global indices. Read about *sub2ind* and *ind2sub*. Check the below demo:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] ;

[m,n] = size(A) ;

% sub indices 
[J,I] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n) ;
% global indices 
idx = sub2ind(size(A),I,J)
```